# Why Chrome Driver isn't launching in asp.net core console app?

Tags: selenium, asp.net-core, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I have **scraping** program which uses chrome driver and selenium. Using .net framework, the code works perfectly **BUT** when I used the .net core framework, chrome driver isn't appearing on the screen. What Might be the cause of this Issue?

Following message gets logged on my console.

> Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 51058
> Only local connections are allowed.
> Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
> ChromeDriver was started successfully.

Main Method:

```cs
foreach (ScrapingUrl objScrapingUrl in ScrapingUrls)
{
    ThreadInfo threadInfo = new ThreadInfo();
    threadInfo.url = objScrapingUrl.ScrapingUrlName;
    threadInfo.attempt = 1;
    threadInfo.urlSubCat = objScrapingUrl.ScrapingUrlNameSubCat;
    
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(StartProcess), threadInfo);
}
```

StartProcess Method:

```cs
private static void StartProcess(object objThreadInfo)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I Am In Thread Process");
    ThreadInfo threadInfo = objThreadInfo as ThreadInfo;
    string categoryUrl = threadInfo.url;
    string subCategoryUrl = threadInfo.urlSubCat;
    int Attempt = threadInfo.attempt;
    IWebDriver driver = CreateDriver(categoryUrl);
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
 }
```

CreateDriver method:

```cs
private static IWebDriver CreateDriver(string categoryUrl)
{
    List<string> proxies = new List<string>() { "163.172.136.226:8811", "51.158.186.242:8811" };
    List<string> userAgents = new List<string>()
    {
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; LG-V410/V41020c Build/LRX22G) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/34.0.1847.118 Safari/537.36"
    };

    ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
    service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

    /* Chrome Options Setting */
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    // options.AddArgument("--headless");
    // options.AddArguments("--proxy-server=" + proxies[RandomNumber(0, proxies.Count - 1)]);
    options.Proxy = null;
    if (categoryUrl.Contains("www.sainsburys.co"))
    {
        // Use only desktop string agent 
        options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
        options.AddArgument($"--user-agent=" + userAgents[RandomNumber(0, 4)]);
    }
    else
    {
        options.AddArgument($"--user-agent=" + userAgents[RandomNumber(0, userAgents.Count - 1)]);
    }
    return new ChromeDriver(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), options);
}
```

Along with it, upon debugging I have noticed my code isn't executing beyond line 59

[image]

My google chrome version and chromium is same which is 83.0.4103

Comment: Is the console application crashing?

Comment: Nothing happens after the message logs on my console so I assume its not crashing But the debug point at line 59 never gets hit as well

Comment: Hm. You might have two problems. The debugger might not be working correctly. Sometimes closing and restarting Visual Studio can fix that. Try adding `Console.WriteLine("Chrome started")` after line 57. Do you see that message in the console?

Comment: Thanks for your time, So what I did is restarted my VS 2019 and run the application. The Issue was same. I have also added `Console.WriteLine("Chrome started")` on line 58 but message didn't appeared. 

Just before `return new ChromeDriver(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), options);` I set Chrome started message and its get printed so I assume this return statement has some problem.

Comment: I am using selenium.webdriver.ChromeDriver package so to create chromedriver.exe in my  bin>debug folder.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the code for the entire method in the image?

Comment: Added few more details, I guess the problem is that Chromedriver isn't launching itself in thread. I can assume it because when I call method CreateDriver()  in my main method right in the beginning and chrome driver appeared on the window.